# OpenGL texture gets worse when moving camera away from object

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, graphical-programming

The texture gets generally worse more I move the camera away from the object. I need to be really close to the object for the texture to be fine. Does anyone know what would cause it and how to fix it?

this is how I load the texture

```
stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(1);
m_Local_buffer = stbi_load(path.c_str(), &m_width, &m_height, &m_bpp, 4);

glGenTextures(1, &m_rendererID);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_rendererID);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, m_width, m_height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, m_Local_buffer);
glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

[image of the bad texture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCzv8.png)

Edit: updated the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that the faces in the model were too close to each other which caused Z-fighting and that caused flickering. It was not caused by texture or my or by OpenGL code like I originally assumed. When I changed the model that had not this issue it worked correctly without any fliggering.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

For [*mipmapping*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mipmap) you have to use one of the mipmap minifying filters. e.g.: `GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR` (see [`glTexParameter`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexParameter.xhtml)):

<s>`glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);`</s>

```cpp
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
```

Comment: I did do this but it still causes the same effect.